# HTTP POST gives 405 error on servlet but works fine on JSP doing the same

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, servlets

None of the other questions related to 405 error make any sense for me.
I'm running Apache Tomcat 9, default installation. During the development the client is on the same machine. I'm getting 405 errors only on POST to servlets. When I turn the servlet to a JSP page, it works fine, also if I use GET on the servlet it works. I'm using an AJAX call. This is the code:

```
function AJAXcommit(url, params) {
  var xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
  xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
  };
xmlHttp.send(params);
}
```

Calling this from javascript function:

```
AJAXcommit("setDefault.jsp","p1=a&p2=b");
```

works fine, but when I use the (almost identical - I created one from the other) Servlet, I get a 405 error:

```
 AJAXcommit("setDefault","p1=a&p2=b");
```

Calling the servlet through a GET works fine, such as standalone (but also from my main page through different AJAX call that uses GET):

```
 http://localhost:8080/myproject/setDefault?p1=a&p2=b
```

The servlet code has only a few lines of servlet specific code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
     String retVar="";
     String p1 = request.getParameter("p1");
     String p2 = request.getParameter("p2");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     // do something with p1 and p2
     out.println("Result="+retVar);
}

 Same for doPost ()  // which solved the problem .....
```

I read something about possible authorization required? but what sort of authorization would that be? Would I have to set up a Tomcat User for this?
I have this problem with 3 different servlets. Using GET, or turning them into JSP's solves it. But I have to consider security, so I rather use POST on a servlet.

Comment: *"None of the other questions related to 405 error make any sense for me"* but you have still nowhere shown your `doPost()` method. All the code posted so far is not relevant to the problem. All of them are client side calls but all of them will fail with the same error because the problem is in your servlet code, not in the client side code. If you include the most minimal code snippet of your `doPost()` method which still reproduces the problem, then we'll be able to point out your mistake.

Comment: Somehow I wasn't thinking that way, as the GET works without a problem, so I suspected the problem in the client, but I guess you're right. I edited my post to add the doGet part. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: So, *"but works fine on JSP doing the same"* was actually not true?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer - I was focused on the client side, ignoring the server. Thanks @BalusC for the remark. The 'doPost()' was missing. Adding that made it work.